# Is there something wrong with this line of code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to take from the user an input integer, and turning to a string in my code.
My line of code for that is:

```
num1 = input(int(str("Enter a number: ")))
```

But the console says: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Enter a number: '
If this line isn't correct can you show me a way how can I turn an integer that is given by the user to a string in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the functions in the wrong order: First you need to turn the input into a Python object, so `input()` has to be the innermost function (to be applied first). Also, `input()` will cast the input as a string by default, so you don't need `str()`.

So the line should read:

```
num1 = input("Enter a number: ")
```